Salesforce: Batch Apex: State
I need to know something about a class that implements the batchable-interface.
If I have a constructor defined, that initialize a non static member variable:
Will the constructor be invoked for every execute-method? Or do I need to implement the stateful-interface too? How would the member variable retain their values?
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
  private final String queryString;
  private final Boolean boolVar;
  private List<Custom_Object__c> customRecords = new List<Custom_Object__c>();

  public MyBatch(
    String queryString,
    Boolean boolVar,
    List<Custom_Object__c> customRecords;
  ) {
    this.queryString = queryString;
    this.boolVar= boolVar;
    this.customRecords = customRecords;
  }
...
}

Shouldn´t it be:
public class MyBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
  private final String queryString;
  private final Boolean boolVar;
  private List<Custom_Object__c> customRecords = new List<Custom_Object__c>();

  public MyBatch(
    String queryString,
    Boolean boolVar,
    List<Custom_Object__c> customRecords;
  ) {
    this.queryString = queryString;
    this.boolVar= boolVar;
    this.customRecords = customRecords;
  }
...
}

Thank you in advance for your answer! When answering, can you send me the documentation, where I can find this information? I have contradictory statements out there.

Queueable, Batchable, and Schedulable classes are serialized at the moment that they are queued for execution (System.enqueueJob, Database.executeBatch, and System.schedule, respectively). During each execution, the properties are deserialized directly from storage, and don't call their constructors. You don't need to worry about their constructors being called again. Constructors are only ever called when using the new keyword to create a new instance of the class in memory.
The only reason why you want to use Database.Stateful is if you expect properties in the Batchable class to change across executions, and you want to retain this data. Note that by implementing Database.Stateful, each execute method will take longer to run, because the state of the class has to be updated each time. You should only use Database.Stateful if you need it, because it does incur a performance penalty.

When you implement a batch class with the Database.Batchable interface, the constructor is invoked only once when the batch job is instantiated. Each execution of the execute method is considered a separate transaction, and the state of non-static member variables is not retained across these transactions by default.
To retain the state of non-static member variables across transactions, you need to implement the Database.Stateful interface. This interface ensures that instance member variables retain their values between transactions.
global class MyTestBatchClass implements Database.Batchable<SObject>, Database.Stateful {
        private Integer counter;

        public MyTestBatchClass() {
                counter = 0; 
        }

        global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
                return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account]);
        }

        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope) {
                counter += scope.size();
                System.debug('Counter value: ' + counter);
        }

        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
                System.debug('Final counter value: ' + counter);
        }
}

If you do not implement Database.Stateful, the counter variable will be reset to its initial value for each execution of the execute method, as each execution is a separate transaction.
